# Convert a list of integers into a string with just one comma after x elements in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert for example this list

```
F=[6, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8]
```

into a string that looks like this:

```
"6 9 4, 3 6 8"
```

the comma after 3 elements in this case is from the length of tuples in another list.

Can't figure out how to do this, I'll be grateful for any help!

Thank you!

Edit: Okay so I am trying to write a progam that "multiplies" to matrizes by adding the elements and finding the minimum. (ci,j = min {ai,k + bk,j})

What I got so far is

```
A="4 3 , 1 7"
B="2 5 9, 8 6 1"

A1 = A.split(",")
B1 = B.split(",")
A2 = [tuple(int(y) for y in x.split()) for x in A1]
B2 = [tuple(int(y) for y in x.split()) for x in B1]

D = []
for k in range(len(A2)):
    for j in range(len(B2[0])):
        C = []
        for i in range(len(A2[0])):
            N = (A2[k][i] + B2[i][j])
            C.append(N)
        D.append((min(C)))
```

So what I wrote gives me the right numbers, but in a list. I tried some codes from the internet but it won't work. The given strings A and B can be matrices of nxm so that I can't just cut the list to two pieces and add them together.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any attempted code to show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use *list comprehension* expression using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> my_list = [6, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8]
>>> n = 3
>>> ', '.join([' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in zip(*[my_list[i::n] for i in range(n)])])
'6 9 4, 3 6 8'
```

Comment: Perfect! This did work for any matrix input, no matter what nxn is! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This actually gives me "6 9 4,3 6 8", how can I add the space for "6 9 4, 3 6 8"?

Comment: I made an edit. I think you copied the code before that. Recheck it

Answer (score 2):

you can try below code:

```
F=[6, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8]
len_other_list = 3
F1 = F[:len_other_list]
F2 = F[len_other_list:]
reqd_string = ' '.join(map(str, F1))+', '+' '.join(map(str, F2))
```

Comment: why do you need `str(', ')` instead of just `, `?

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
' '.join([str(i) if c != 3 else str(i)+', ' for c,i in enumerate(F,start=1)])
```

This will join all the elements by a space, adding a comma after the third element. Change the `3` in the line if you want to add the comma after a different element. The `enumerate` function is counting the number of elements in `F` with the index starting at `1`.

The `join` string method will concatenate all elements of your list by `' '` (space).

Comment: There'll be a trailing space in the string

Comment: true. do `' '.join([str(i) if c != 3 else str(i)+','...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. 1 with regex also :)

```
import re

f = [6, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8]
a = re.sub(r"[\[\],]",r"", ''.join(str(f)))
print "\""+a[:5]+','+a[5:]+"\""
```

Output:

```
"6 9 4, 3 6 8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
F=[6, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]
size = 3

s = ', '.join([' '.join(map(str, F[i:i+size])) for i in range(0, len(F), size)])
```